# How to get token usage for each openAI ChatCompletion API call in streaming mode?

Tags: openai-api

According to openAI's documentation,
https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/chat-vs-completions
you should get token usage from the response. However, I am currently working making the API call with stream set to True. The response doesn't seem to contain usage property?

So how can I get the token usage in this case?

Comment: can you add the code you use to call the api?

Comment: Heya, were you finally able to get it? I am struggling to get it in streaming mode as well (but using node, not python

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue; one difference is I'm trying Azure open-ai and I'm not a consumer using SDK I'm more like a platform team to enable this to a large team - who is the ideal consumer

Answer (score 0):

you can use [tiktoken](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb)

`pip install tiktoken`

```py
import tiktoken

def num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0301"):
    """Returns the number of tokens used by a list of messages."""
    try:
        encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model(model)
    except KeyError:
        print("Warning: model not found. Using cl100k_base encoding.")
        encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")
    if model == "gpt-3.5-turbo":
        print("Warning: gpt-3.5-turbo may change over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-3.5-turbo-0301.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0301")
    elif model == "gpt-4":
        print("Warning: gpt-4 may change over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-4-0314.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-4-0314")
    elif model == "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301":
        tokens_per_message = 4  # every message follows <|start|>{role/name}\n{content}<|end|>\n
        tokens_per_name = -1  # if there's a name, the role is omitted
    elif model == "gpt-4-0314":
        tokens_per_message = 3
        tokens_per_name = 1
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"""num_tokens_from_messages() is not implemented for model {model}. See https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/chatml.md for information on how messages are converted to tokens.""")
    num_tokens = 0

    if type(messages) == "list":
        for message in messages:
            num_tokens += tokens_per_message
            for key, value in message.items():
                num_tokens += len(encoding.encode(value))
                if key == "name":
                    num_tokens += tokens_per_name
        num_tokens += 3  # every reply is primed with <|start|>assistant<|message|>
    elif type(messages) == "str":
        num_tokens += len(encoding.encode(messages))
    return num_tokens
```

```py
import openai

result = []

for chunk in openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Who won the world series in 2020?"},
        {"role": "assistant", "content": "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."},
        {"role": "user", "content": "Where was it played?"}
    ], # this is prompt_tokens ex) prompt_tokens=num_tokens_from_messages(messages)
    stream=True
):
    content = chunk["choices"][0].get("delta", {}).get("content")
    if content:
        result.append(content)


# Usage of completion_tokens
completion_tokens = num_tokens_from_messages("".join(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to count the `prompt_tokens` and `completion_tokens` manually and add them up to get the total usage count.

**Measuring `prompt_tokens`:**

Using any of the [tokenizer](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb) it is possible to count the `prompt_tokens` in the request body.

**Measuring the `completion_tokens`:**

You need to have an intermittent service (a proxy), that can pass on  the SSE(server sent events) to the client applications post counting the tokens in each response.

A sample architecture is present here: https://medium.com/microsoftazure/when-invoking-apis-hosted-by-azure-api-management-configured-azure-openai-service-as-a-backend-bd8f2648cfa5

Answer (score 0):

All the provided answers have the core solution which is we have to use some kind of proxy to handle the token calculation(i.e,tiktoken) using our custom way. Here, with my answer I would like to share the implementation way of Azure OpenAI

The logic here is to build a reverse-proxy [(yarp-ms reverse proxy)](https://github.com/microsoft/reverse-proxy). You can find the full project from [Enterprise-azureai-proxy](https://github.com/Azure/enterprise-azureai/tree/main/src/dotnet/AzureAI.Proxy)

The below is one major part of the solution of handling the stream

```
﻿using AsyncAwaitBestPractices;
using Azure.Core;
using AzureAI.Proxy.Models;
using AzureAI.Proxy.OpenAIHandlers;
using AzureAI.Proxy.Services;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Transforms;
using Yarp.ReverseProxy.Transforms.Builder;

namespace AzureAI.Proxy.ReverseProxy;

internal class OpenAIChargebackTransformProvider : ITransformProvider
{
   
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly IManagedIdentityService _managedIdentityService;
    private readonly ILogIngestionService _logIngestionService;
   
    private string accessToken = "";

    private TokenCredential _managedIdentityCredential;

    public OpenAIChargebackTransformProvider(
        IConfiguration config, 
        IManagedIdentityService managedIdentityService,
        ILogIngestionService logIngestionService)
    {
        _config = config;
        _managedIdentityService = managedIdentityService;
        _logIngestionService = logIngestionService;
               
        _managedIdentityCredential = _managedIdentityService.GetTokenCredential();

    }

    public void ValidateRoute(TransformRouteValidationContext context) { return; }

    public void ValidateCluster(TransformClusterValidationContext context) { return; }
    
    public void Apply(TransformBuilderContext context)
    {
        context.AddRequestTransform(async requestContext => {
            //enable buffering allows us to read the requestbody twice (one for forwarding, one for analysis)
            requestContext.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();

            //check accessToken before replacing the Auth Header
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) || OpenAIAccessToken.IsTokenExpired(accessToken, _config["EntraId:TenantId"]))
            {
                accessToken = await OpenAIAccessToken.GetAccessTokenAsync(_managedIdentityCredential, CancellationToken.None);
            }

            //replace auth header with the accesstoken of the managed indentity of the proxy
            requestContext.ProxyRequest.Headers.Remove("api-key");
            requestContext.ProxyRequest.Headers.Remove("Authorization");
            requestContext.ProxyRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");

        });
        context.AddResponseTransform(async responseContext =>
        {
            var originalStream = await responseContext.ProxyResponse.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            string capturedBody = "";

            // Buffer for reading chunks
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            int bytesRead;

            // Read, inspect, and write the data in chunks - this is especially needed for streaming content
            while ((bytesRead = await originalStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                // Convert the chunk to a string for inspection
                var chunk = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                capturedBody += chunk;

                // Write the unmodified chunk back to the response
                await responseContext.HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            //flush any remaining content to the client
            await responseContext.HttpContext.Response.CompleteAsync();

            //now perform the analysis and create a log record
            var record = new LogAnalyticsRecord();
            record.TimeGenerated = DateTime.UtcNow;
            
            if (responseContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Consumer"].ToString() != "")
            {
                record.Consumer = responseContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Consumer"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                record.Consumer = "Unknown Consumer";
            }
           
            bool firstChunck = true;
            var chunks = capturedBody.Split("data:");
            foreach (var chunk in chunks)
            {
                var trimmedChunck = chunk.Trim();
                if (trimmedChunck != "" && trimmedChunck != "[DONE]")
                {

                    JsonNode jsonNode = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(trimmedChunck);
                    if (jsonNode["error"] is not null)
                    {
                        Error.Handle(jsonNode);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string objectValue = jsonNode["object"].ToString();

                        switch (objectValue)
                        {
                            case "chat.completion":
                                Usage.Handle(jsonNode, ref record);
                                record.ObjectType = objectValue;
                                break;
                            case "chat.completion.chunk":
                                if (firstChunck)
                                {
                                    record = Tokens.CalculateChatInputTokens(responseContext.HttpContext.Request, record);
                                    record.ObjectType = objectValue;
                                    firstChunck = false;
                                }
                                ChatCompletionChunck.Handle(jsonNode, ref record);
                                break;
                            case "list":
                                if (jsonNode["data"][0]["object"].ToString() == "embedding")
                                {
                                    record.ObjectType = jsonNode["data"][0]["object"].ToString();
                                    //it's an embedding
                                    Usage.Handle(jsonNode, ref record);
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            record.TotalTokens = record.InputTokens + record.OutputTokens;
            _logIngestionService.LogAsync(record).SafeFireAndForget();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also use get_openai_callback() if you use Lagchain

```
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback

        with get_openai_callback() as cb:
            response = qa({"question": prompt, "chat_history": chat_history})

            print(f"Prompt Tokens: {cb.prompt_tokens}")
            print(f"Completion Tokens: {cb.completion_tokens}")
            print(f"Total Cost (USD): ${cb.total_cost}")
```

Comment: That doesn't work with streaming, which is the question here.